# update opportunity contact role

Tags: opportunitycontactrole

I am trying to update the opportunity contact role object.

How to i find the id of the contactrole?  What do i need to be updating?

I have tried:

```
$url = "/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/OpportunityContactRole";
    $d['OpportunityId'] = $oppId;
    $d['ContactId'] = $contactId;
    $d['Role'] = $role;

Result : patch not allowed




$url = "/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/OpportunityContactRole/".$oppId;
    $d['ContactId'] = $contactId;
    $d['Role'] = $role;

Result:: Record not found





$url = "/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/OpportunityContactRole/".$contactId;
    $d['OpportunityId'] = $oppId;
    $d['Role'] = $role;

Result:: Record not found
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the contactroleId.  It is not defined on the salesforce dev pages, but it is just like any other object.

Id is the field name.